# UIScrollview offset issue

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

having a bit of an issue here. My navigation controller has a scrollview that sits perfectly upon first visit, but after pushing through a button to another view controller, and then navigating back, the Scrollview is offset by about 200 or so, any ideas what the issue could be?

Here is the view when it's first loaded -

http://imgur.com/bXV6X,rCrSi#0

And here is it after navigation to another view and then pushing the "back button"

http://imgur.com/bXV6X,rCrSi#1

Any help would be much appreciated on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant really tell what is causing this issue, but if nothing else try setting the frame of your scroll view every time the view appears to the correct position.

Like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     myScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
}
```

Pick the x, y, width and height from the interface builder. Or play with the positions until you're satisfied. Or try to paste in some code so we can see whats causing you this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set it's frame in view and it will appear and than it will show on the right or you can set its center point to produce same result I hope you understand if any question comment.